# What do you call a person who walks their own path?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I am not really talking about in a religious or spiritual way but I was wondering if there's such word that can be used on groups like the artists and the creatives that walks their own path.

**For example:** it would be an artist who doesn't imitate what the majority but he or she would walk their own path to find their own art.

Comment: Thank you! So for example, it would be an artist who doesn't imitate what the majority but he or she would walk their own path to find their own art. I guess you can also relate this to Picasso. He used to draw really good ( as in what the people thought what beautiful art should be ) but after awhile he got tired of it. In a sense, he walked his own path after that.

Comment: Look in a thesaurus for all the synonyms of nonconformist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Maverick (noun):** If you describe someone as a maverick, you mean that they are unconventional and independent, and do not think or behave in the same way as other people. [(Collins)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/maverick)

**Example:** He was too much of a maverick ever to hold high office.

✥━━━━✥━━━━✥

**Autonomous (adj):** independent and having the power to make your own decisions. ([Cambridge English dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/autonomous))

✥━━━━✥━━━━✥

**Self-determined (adj):** 
1Having one's actions, course of life, form of government, etc., determined by oneself; practising self-determination; autonomous. [(Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/self-determined)

### ☆━━✥✥✥━━☆☆━━✥✥✥━━☆☆━━✥✥✥━━☆